# WSO2 API Manager Bad Certificate

Tags: wso2

I am trying to use the WSO2 API manager to publish an internal SCIM / REST service and have it configured / validated in the publisher, but when trying to use the store / API console to run some validations, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

in the console, and in the apigw-error log receive the below message:

```
2018-10-01 19:05:46,976 [-] [HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1] ERROR 
SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.decryptData(SSLIOSession.java:378)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:413)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:218)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have imported the endpoint API certificates into the API manager java keystore but still seem to be getting this error message.  Do you know what could be causing this?

Nick

Comment: Did you accept the certificate of the API Manager from the browser?

Comment: Yes, I browsed to the direct call and accepted the certificate.

Comment: Try to put the backend certificate (or whole chain) into the truststore. Isn't the backend expecting a client auth mutual ssl?